# PyInstaller Exe cant right click

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I just created my very first exe with PyInstaller and everything is working great except for the fact that I cant copy paste something into the cmd window.. I've tried right clicking and pasting but when I right click nothing happends.. Do I need to add code to the script?

Comment: What does your exe _do_?  Are you prompting the user for `input`?  Are you showing a console and sleeping?  Are you generating a window?  This question is too broadly vague to know how to help you.

Comment: Fixed it, I just use the top left icon to use edit > paste done and done